# Determine overall space complexity of the program

Tags: algorithm

In a program, I’m using two data structures

1: An array of pointers of size k, each pointer points to a link lists(hence, total ‘k’ lists) . Total number of nodes in all the lists = M…..(something like hashing with separate chaining, k is fixed, M can vary)

2: Another array of integers of size M  (where M=number of nodes above)
Question is: What is the overall space complexity of the program? Is it something like below?

First part: O(k+M) or just O(M)….both are correct I guess!

Second part: O(2M) or just O(M)…again both correct?

Overall O(k+M) + O(2M) ==> O(max(k+M, 2M)
Or just O(M)?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

O(K+M) is O(M) if the M is always greater than K. So, the final result is O(M).

First part: O(k+M) is not correct its just O(M)

Second part: O(2M) is not correct because we don't use constants in order so correct is O(M)

Overall O(M) + O(M) ==> O(M).

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct in the two cases. But since `O(k+M) = O(M)`, supposing `k` constant, everybody will use the simplest notation, which is O(M).

For the second part, a single array is O(M).

For the overall, it would be `O(k+M+M) = O(max(k+M,2M)) = O(M)` (we can "forget" multiplicative and additive constants in the big-O notation - except if your are in constant time).

As a reminder `g(x) = O(f(x))` *iff* there exist `x0` and `c` such that `x>x0` implies `g(x) >= c.f(x)`